# Specific Javascript Object from any XML

Tags: javascript, xml

On my server there are hundreds of **xml-files**. One of these files may look like this:

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
<teiHeader>
    <fileDesc>
        <titleStmt>
            <title>Diary of Robert Graves 1935-39 and ancillary material</title>
            <author>Robert Graves</author>
            <editor>...</editor>
        </titleStmt>
        <publicationStmt>
            <publisher>...</publisher>
            <pubPlace>...</pubPlace>
            <availability status="unknown">
                <p>...</p>
            </availability>
            <date>...</date>
        </publicationStmt>
        <sourceDesc>
            <p>...</p>
        </sourceDesc>
    </fileDesc>
    <profileDesc>
        <particDesc>
            <listPerson>
                <person xml:id="AH">
                    <p>Alan Hodge. Oxford history graduate. Became close friends with Laura Riding &amp; Robert Graves. First husband of Beryl Graves.</p>
                </person>
                <person xml:id="BP">
                    <p>Beryl Pritchard. Daughter of Harry and Amy Pritchard, Robert Graves's second wife. Formerly married to Alan Hodge. Robert and Beryl had four children: William, Lucia, Juan and Tomas.</p>
                </person>
                <person xml:id="DR">
                    <p>David Reeves. Brother of James Reeves.</p>
                </person>
            </listPerson>
        </particDesc>
    </profileDesc>
</teiHeader>
<facsimile>
    <surface xml:id="graves1938-10-10-1">
        <graphic url="graves1938-10-10.jpg"/>
    </surface>
</facsimile>
<text>
    <front>
        <div type="abstract">
            <head>OCTOBER 1938</head>
            <p>The rains set in, and Graves works in his bedroom with the fire going. ...</p>
        </div>
    <!-- abstracts for other months -->
    </front>
    <body>
        <div type="diaryentry" n="1938-10-10">
            <head>Oct 10 <del>Tuesday.</del><add>Monday</add></head>
            <p>Ghost, completing <abbr>ch</abbr> IX</p>
            <p>Dictionary with <rs ref="#AH">Alan</rs>.</p>
            <p>A lot of time goes to making charcoal for 'Marthe',  <rs ref="#BP">Beryl</rs>'s now using this <foreign>fugon</foreign> <note>charcoal-burner</note> for warming her attic.</p>
            <p>Went to Montauban with <rs ref="#DR">David</rs> – first visit for about 10 days – <del>got</del> <add>ordered</add> small wood for  Dorothy's cresset.</p>
            <p>Now almost always win at Cambeluk: we are playing a correspondence game with Harry.</p>
            <p>Nono broke Laura's particular coffee cup, <figure><figDesc>sketch of cup</figDesc></figure> and she her blue glass bottle given by Karl.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- other entries -->
    </body>
</text>
```

*To formulate it even clearer:* The only thing that the **xml-files** share is their file extension, but no structural xml-patterns.

---

For each of these **xml-files** residing on my server I want to generate a **Javascript-Object**, which would be -for the example above- looking as follows:

```
{
root: {
    text: "TEI",
    children: [{text: "teiHeader", 
                children:[{text: "fileDesc", 
                           children:[{text:"titleStmt", 
                                      children:[{text:"title"},{text:"author"},{text:"editor"}]},
                                     {text:"publicationStmt", 
                                      children:[{text:"publisher"},{text:"pubPlace"},{text:"availability", 
                                                                                      children:[{text:"p"}]},{text:"date"}]},
                                     {text:"sourceDesc", 
                                      children:[{text:"p"}]}]},
                          {text: "profileDesc", 
                           children:[{text:"particDesc",
                                      children:[{text:"listPerson", 
                                                 children:[{text:"person"},{text:"person"},{text:"person"}]}]}]}]},
               {text:"fascimile",  
                children:[{text:"surface", 
                           children:[{text:"graphic"}]}]},
               {text:"text", 
                children:[{text:"front", 
                           children:[{text:"div", 
                                      children:[{text:"head"},{text:"p"}]}]},
                          {text:"body",
                           children:[{text:"div", 
                                      children:[{text:"head", 
                                                 children:[{text:"del"},{text:"add"}]},{text:"p", 
                                                                                        children:[{text:"abbr"}]},{text:"p", 
                                                                                                                   children:[{text:"rs"}]},{text:"p", 
                                                                                                                                            children:[{text:"rs"},{text:"foreign"},{text:"note"}]},{text:"p", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    children:[{text:"rs"},{text:"del"},{text:"add"}]},{text:"p"},{text:"p",
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  children:[{text:"figure",
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             children:[{text:"figDesc"}]}]}]}]}]}]
}
}
```

---

In words: The xml-tree-structure is mapped unto a Javascript-object by nesting inner tags in children-properties and tag-names in text-properties.

---

I manually typed the above example. I dont know, but although the principle seems easy, I think its pretty complicated.

I thought of *parsing* the XML using a **pure client-side javascript Xml-Parser**, which you can find [here](http://xmljs.sourceforge.net/index.html).

Maybe with the **Sax-Parser** incorporated inside *above API* i could do something using the **Sax-Events** like `SAXDocumentHandler.startElement (name, atts)` and `SAXDocumentHandler.endElement (name)`.

But even with this parser I am struggling to implement something due to the variable structure of my XMLs. I can't think of any clever way to iterate over it.

***Can you help me to construct the Javascript-Objects?***

Answer (score 0):

Did you try https://code.google.com/p/x2js/?

It seems it is what you need:

> This library provides XML to JSON (JavaScript Objects) and vice versa
>   javascript conversion functions. The library is very small and doesn't
>   require any other additional libraries.

Comment: Really nice, but does not seem to generate the JSON of the form I need right away. Using that library i would also need to think of a clever way to iterate and build the JSON object with different nesting levels and properties `root` ---> `children` ---> `text`.